# Why does square angle occur while drawing an ellipse in C#?

Tags: c#, ellipse

The reason of me asking this question is in the picture:

[image: Screenshot visually illustrating the problem in the question]

For some reason while drawing an ellipse using System.Drawing a square angle occurs. Below you can see how I had drawn it. I haven't found the solution BUT in one video(how to make a simple graphic editor) sq. angle appears during the draw of an ellipse and then it disappears. Full code: https://pastebin.com/465eD7Zf Tried on NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET 5. FillRectangle works.

```
private void paintBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw)
        {
            Graphics g = paintBox.CreateGraphics();
            Item currItem = (Item)choice.SelectedItem;
            
            switch (currItem)
            {
                case Item.Rectangle:
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(showColor.BackColor), x, y, e.X - x, e.Y - y);
                    break;
                case Item.Ellipse:
                    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(showColor.BackColor), x, y, e.X - x, e.Y - y); // ???
                    break;
                
            }
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using CreateGraphics() is a notoriously buggy way to paint.  Use the Paint event, Invalidate() to update the drawing.

Comment: Hint: Don't draw on mouse move!!!! Windows handles drawing by sending `WM_PAINT` message to your app, which in turns fires a `.Paint()` event on the form and each control. Handle that event to draw your graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not erasing the previously drawn ellipse, so, as the user drags, you see all the ellipses.